# Thanks for re-reopening the following question

Tags: support

The following ***[question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515897/what-is-a-word-for-the-feeling-of-constantly-wanting-new-possessions)***, besides being formulated in a much more detailed way, offers a lot of good information in answers that the “supposed original one” does not.

Comment: Reopened. Thanks!!!

Comment: Erm...closed again...

Comment: @Cascabel - yes I already launched the campaign re-reopen.

Comment: I thought the "new" question was much better in terms of Q&A quality than the dupe. However, the OP does need to supply a sample sentence.

Comment: @Cascabel - of course, but the intransigent  spirit of some  users calls for closing at all costs. I think the OP has provided above average details of what they are looking for, but....   ***be nice policy at its best.***

Comment: It was most recently closed for failing the SWR requirement, but the OP has just edited it to add the requisite sentence (although the syntax used does to some degree invalidate many of the existing answers). I'm still on strike for Monica, but those still actively undertaking community moderation tasks might like to vote to reopen it now...

Comment: It only needs one more reopen vote. This is a success for letting OPs fix their own questions.

Answer (score 6):

Although I'm not a fan of single-word requests, I am a fan of due process, and the process established at EL&U for closing a question involves identifying—from a menu of rationales for closure—some specific fault in the question and closing it for that reason. Once that fault is corrected, however, the specific rationale for closure loses its validity and there is no reason, as a matter of due process, for the question to remain closed under the no-longer-applicable close reason.

In this particular case, the question poster seems to be quite interested in satisfying the formal requirements for a question at this site. Evidently, close voters have already closed the question for two separate reasons, each of which has subsequently been addressed through edits of the question.

Assuming that the current closure is eventually overturned, it is certainly possible that a third close reason—such as "duplicate of an existing question"—may justify closing the question a third time. But I hope that site participants don't adopt as their attitude toward question closure the view of a hanging judge in a frontier town: "I don't care if he's guilty of the specific charges that the prosecution laid against him; I just care that he gets hanged."

Answer (score -1):

> Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests

Please stop attempting to solicit people to break this community's self-determined quality standards. This question should be closed.

And don't you dare try to edit it. Only the OP can know the context they want to use it in in order to show us how they want to use it. Only they know if they want a noun, adjective, or verb.

Comment: The information provided by the OP are clear and detailed enough to convey what they are looking for. Btw who are you to say “*don’t dare to try to edit it*” ???? Editing posts to improve them is part of SE policy to help users. Please  consult the rules.

Comment: @user067531 So does the OP want a noun or adjective? The answers are giving both. If it's so clear the answers should only be for one word class. And what rules ever allow you to edit in fabricated evidence or requirements? We edit to improve posts, but not change the substance of them. The problem with this question is its substance fails to meet the community determined quality standards. Please consult them if you are not aware of them.

Comment: If it was so clear what the OP wanted, then why would they comment this on your answer? "This is a good word, but I feel that it is not a good fit for my particular scenario because it describes a group of people or society rather than an individual." If it was so clear you shouldn't have been able to write an answer that didn't address their desire.